# Wildfly deployment issue

Tags: java, wildfly

I have an ear project which contains below module :

1. RedemtionService
2. RedemptionWeb
3. RedemtionBean
4. RedemptionCache
5. RedemptionCommon

In local wildfly server I have deployed it successfully but when I am going to deploy this another production server then it's throwing an below exception :

```
2016-06-07 14:46:06,289 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Test.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionCache.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionCache.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionBeans.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionBeans.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionService.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionService.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test.ear\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl]"
    ],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionBeans.jar\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionCache.jar\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionService.jar\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionWeb.war\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test.ear\".INSTALL"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionBeans.jar\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionCache.jar\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test.ear\".\"RedemptionService.jar\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test.ear\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.CacheDaoImpl",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.FGSFDaoImpl",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionBeans.GenericDAOImpl",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionCache.AppCacheService",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.AsyncSMSServiceImpl",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFRedeemServiceImpl",
            "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test.RedemptionService.FGSFServiceImpl",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]
```

How can I solve this issue? I am searching for this solution form last 2 days but still not found anything.

Comment: what are the versions of your local and production wildflies?

Comment: @Sergio Both are same 8.2.0 final

Comment: are both wildflies started in same mode? (e.g., standalone.xml vs standalone-full.xml?) is the http port free?

Comment: @user140547 HTTP post free means? And yes both are starting in same mode (standard.xml)

Answer (score 1):

By default, classes in one module in an ear deployment do not have access to classes of other modules. You have to provide a  jboss-deployment-structure.xml and override the default behaviour. You have to set ear-subdeployments-isolated to false to enable sharing of classes. For more details, consult the part about EAR class loading in the following link:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly?_sscc=t

Comment: ear-subdeployments-isolated  this property already set to false in wildfly

Comment: By looking at the error log, it seems that weld failed to register the beans Maybe beans.xml is missing? Or maybe you are starting wildfly in JEE-light profile, causing those beans to fail(because they depend on subsystems like JMS, etc)

Comment: What is JEE-Light profile? Right now I am opening in full-ha profile?